# After a span, copy text inside the next <a>...</a> link with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

For a list of Chinese character dictionary webpages, I need to extract the text displayed inside the `<a>...</a>` element right after the `<span>Radical:</span>` element. Here's the sample code of the website:

[https://www.archchinese.com/chinese_english_dictionary.html?find=松](https://www.archchinese.com/chinese_english_dictionary.html?find=%E6%9D%BE)

`<br>
<span>»&nbsp;Radical:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
<a target="_archchinese" class="char-effect" style="font-family: KaiTi,STKaiti,DFKai-SB,BiauKai,Arial !important;font-size:1.5em !important;color: #0000FF !important; " href="https://www.archchinese.com/chinese_english_dictionary.html?find=木">木</a>`

from which I only want to extract the "木" i.e. the text displayed inside the `<a>...</a>` element.

I have already tried:

- `driver.find_elements_by_xpath(/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/a[6]`

but the variable a[x] changes for different pages, subject to the number of links contained in the `<div id="charDef">` divider that holds several variables on each Chinese character page. Moreover, names of the attributes that I assume could be used for singling out this `<a>...</a>` element such as target, class, partial link etc. seem to appear in many other elements on the page i.e. are not unique.

In this case, how can I simply make Selenium extract the text between `<a>...</a>` in the element that appears right after the `<span>Radical:</span>` element?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you familiar with the different ways of selecting elements in Selenium?

Comment: Yes sorry - the issue here is that I need to loop through many webpages for different Chinese characters, not just one - so the ending of the webpage address I posted above will change to =松, =础, =叫...and so on - in each of them the value in a[X] at the end of the XPATH to copy the radical character text will change - a[6], a[3], a[8]. The constant fact is that this character always appears after the <span>Radical:</span> element as the text displayed by the next <a>...</a> element (as you will notice in the code I posted above) - how do I instruct selenium to copy it based on this logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get("https://www.archchinese.com/chinese_english_dictionary.html?find=%E6%9D%BE")
```

**Old section**

```
warning = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='charDetailPane']//a[6]")))
print warning.text
```

**Updated section:**

```
//span[contains(text(),'Radical:')]/following-sibling::a
```

Note :

Add below imports to your code

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

**Output:**

木

Comment: Dipak - I can't simply put a[6] at the end of the xpath - I need to loop through many webpages for different Chinese characters, not just one - thus the ending of the webpage address I posted above will change to =松, =础, =叫...and so on - in each of them the value in a[X] at the end of the XPATH to copy the radical character will change - a[6], a[3], a[8]. The constant fact is that this character always appears after the <span>Radical</span> element as the text displayed by the next <a>...</a> element - how  do I instruct selenium to copy it based on this logic?

Comment: Ok, your statement is bit contradictory over here you want text after <span>Radical</span> element as the text displayed by the next <a>...</a>(木 in above case) element. and at the same time you are saying radical will change character - a[6], a[3], a[8]. In above above code even if text changes it will always give you text of <a>...</a> for Radical.

Comment: Dipak - apologies If unclear - the XPATH for the <a>...</a> element (the displayed text of which I want to copy) will change when I loop the dictionary website for different characters. So, on the webpage for character 松 the XPATH for the element will end with a[6], but for 础, the XPATH will end with a[3] - so using a fixed XPATH ending like a[6] when I’m looping through many character pages is no good. The constant characteristic of the <a>...</a> element, the displayed text of which I want to copy, is that it always appear right after the <span>Radical:</span> element in the HTML code.

Comment: Dipak - I used the same logic as you did in the updated section, just adapted it to my code - worked perfectly, thank you! driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Radical:')]/following-sibling::a").text

Comment: Great can you please accept answer and hit upvote button

Comment: would you kind enough to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answer from your end.

Comment: Done! Thank you.